# Put Page as Content for ScrollViewer or ContentControl etc

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to put a `Page` inside a `<Grid/>`, `<StackPanel/>`, `<ContentControl/>` or `<ScrollViewer/>` as content from code using a constructor call?

I expect such things:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
     <ScrollViewer Content="{Binding Panel0}"/>
</Grid>
```

**C#:**

```
public class TestWindowViewModel : Page
{
   public string Name { get; private set; }
   public string Description { get; private set; }
   public TestWindowViewModel(string name, string description)
   {
       Name = name;
       Description = description;
    }
}
```

_

```
public partial class SomeViewModel : Page
{
    public TestWindowViewModel Panel0;

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        Panel0 = new TestWindowViewModel("panelName", "panelDescription"); 
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use usercontrols instead of pages.  You can host a usercontrol in any contentcontrol. Pages have to be in a frame and frames come with a load of complications.
The only time I would use frame and page is when a user is filling in a number of them for one particular action and they might want to cycle back and forth through the list of pages. Like a wizard.  Pages can retain user input state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Frame` tag

```cs
<ScrollViewer>
<Frame content = "{Binding MyPage}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If you don't want to have a prop in your ViewModel then you should be able to do

```cs
<ScrollViewer>
<Frame>
<Frame.Content>
<locals:MyPage>
</Frame.Content>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Keep in mind you have something called `TestWindowViewModel` and it inherits Page. This is not a ViewModel. Instead it is a normal page.

You want something that looks like this:

```cs
    public class NotifyPropertyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private Page myPage;

        public Page MyPage
        {
            get { return myPage; }
            set
            {
                myPage = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    }
```

and you can go a level farther and make an abstract class:

```cs
    public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

and then you can just inherit ViewModel like so:

```cs
public class TestWindow: Page
{
   public TestWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class TestWindowViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string description;

        public string Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set
            {
                Description = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    }
```

Once you get this all seperated out correctly you can use the frame and do the same for the SomePage and SomePageViewModel and then you can use actual binding on the Frame Content from the ViewModel. I know this is long winded, but if you start out right on setting up a good MVVM setup you will save yourself headache if you ever get into Async and what not.

Answer (score 0):

in xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Frame x:Name="CurrentPage" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"></Frame>
</ScrollViewer>
```

in cs:

```
CurrentPage.Content = content;
```

where content is Page

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but there is the issue of this is bad practice. You want to use the Code behind as little as possible and this is just setting up for failure.

Comment: @BenjaminFurlani its also possible if you want to bind the content in xaml if you don't want to write it in cs

Comment: True, but I am basing my comment off of your answer to set `CurrentPage.Content = content`